# Prevent API call in component when navigating back to it

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have the following components:

1. `App`: the root component, which contains the routes to other components using React Router DOM.
2. `MovieScreen`, shown when visiting `movies/:id`.
3. `LoginScreen`, shown when the user needs to login before performing an action.

---

Consider this scenario:

1. The user visits `/movies/awesome-movie`. `MovieScreen` component is rendered and based on the ID, the movie data is fetched and displayed. Loading happens in `useEffect()`.
2. The user tries to do an action that requires authentication, like marking the movie as watched. To authenticate, I show a link to the `LoginScreen`, like this:

```
<Link to="/login">
    <Button>Login</Button>
</Link>
```

The user presses the button and goes to `LoginScreen`.

3. In `LoginScreen`, the user presses the **Back** button and **navigates back to `MovieScreen`**.

What happens now is that the movie data is re-loaded, losing any UI state. I'd like to avoid this situation.

As I understand, the React way to solve this is to "push state up".

An idea I have is to load the movie data in the `App` component and only when it's loaded show `MovieScreen`.

Is my idea a good solution? Are there other, better solutions?

Comment: You said "What happens now is that the movie data is re-loaded, losing any UI state. I'd like to avoid this situation". What do you mean, in this case by "losing any UI state"?

Comment: For example: 1) Scrolling state is lost, as the view scrolls to top and 2) if a a dialog was shown in `MovieScreen` it's now not shown.